# Regular expressions, multiple gsub, /1 and $1

Tags: ruby, regex

There's an example using regular expressions from CodeWars. It's supposed to find words and substitute them with a slang.

```
def gym_slang(phrase)
  phrase.gsub(/([pP])robably/, "\\1rolly")
    .gsub(/([iI])\sam/, "\\1'm")
    .gsub(/([Ii])nstagram/, "\\1nsta")
    .gsub(/([Dd])o\snot/, "\\1on't")
    .gsub(/([gG])oing to/, "\\1onna")
    .gsub(/([Cc])ombination/, "\\1ombo")
end
```

1. Why doesn't `$1` work in this example? I thought the difference between `$1` and `\1` is the first one is available globally, while the second is available only in the method where matching and grouping took place.
2. Why do we need to escape it twice? Why doesn't just `\1` work?
3. Why does the method stop working when I do separate the `gsub`s? It works only when I chain the `gsub` methods.

Comment: Avoid using double quotes if Ruby supports single quotes use that. The `'$1'` should work. And `"\1"` is probably interpreted as _octal_ 1.

Answer (score 2):

> why isn't $1 working in this example (I tried)?

Because you are using `gsub` without a block. The arguments are evaluated before the method call, so there is no way a regex match is reflected in the replacement string if it is given as an argument.

> why we need to escape it twice? Why just \1 doesn't work?

Because `"\1"` evaluates to `"\u0001"`, which is a different character.

> Why method stops working when I do separate gsubs?

Because if you just have non-destructive method calls, the strings created by `gsub` will just be thrown away in place.

Comment: Beat me to it :). +1.

Comment: Thank you very much, so it means \\1 is something different than \1, right? I've never seen it before, I have to read about it.

Comment: `"\\1"` and `'\1'` are the same . They are different from `"\1"`.

Comment: Thank you, everything clear now. I simply overlooked double quotes.